# Propagate forward with a different value

Tags: python

I have a random list of 0/1:

```
import random
import numpy as np
x = np.array([random.randint(0,1) for ii in range(0,10000)])
```

I want to implement a "mute-forward" logic in `x`: when a 1 is detected, mute the following 21 elements in `x` to 0, regardless of the original value.

The following code does exactly that:

```
idx_check = 0
for idx in range(0, len(x)):
    if idx < idx_check:
        continue

    if x[idx]==1:
        x[(idx+1):(idx+roll_window+1)] = 0
        idx_check = idx_check + roll_window + 1
```

Is there a built-in function or a smart Pandas method that does this?

Comment: Where does Pandas come in? Do you have a dataframe somewhere that you're not showing, but that you want to apply this to?

Comment: No, there isn't any built in function that does this specifically and I don't know of anything that could make this more concise. I suggest posting on [codereview.se] for feedback on working code. Be sure you read their rules before posting, though.

Comment: No this question alone has nothing to do with Pandas. I only assumed Pandas might be a fishing pond because of the `ffill` method

Comment: Er, this code doesn't work. I get `TypeError: can only assign an iterable` at `x[(idx+1):(idx+roll_window+1)] = 0`. Assigning a scalar to a slice would work with a NumPy array though.

Comment: @wjandrea apologies I edited the code that generates `x`

Comment: What if there's a `1` at index`10` and again at index `20`? Do you "mute" the element at index `35` (which is outside the range of the `1` at index `10`, but inside the range of the `1` at index `20`)?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi  no I don't mute index 35 in that case.